# Field has incomplete type in forward declaration

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I reproduce an error with the following simple file.

It says:

*field has incomplete type 'Foo'*

**bar.h:**

```
class Foo;

class Bar{
    private:
        int x_;
        Foo foo_; // error: incomplete type

    public:
        void setx(int x) {x_ = x;};
        void increment(int);

};


class Foo{

public:
    void run(int y,Bar& bar) {bar.setx(y);};
};

void Bar::increment(int i){foo_.run(i,*this);}
```

Member *foo_* must not be a reference or a pointer. The reason for this is that in my actual code,  I cannot initialize Foo in the initialization list of Bar.

Comment: To declare an *instance* of a class, the full definition of the class is needed. On the other hand, to declare a reference a forward-declaration is all that is needed. I suggest you experiment with the order of your classes and member function definitions.

Comment: *I cannot initialize Foo in the initialization list of Bar.* Then you can't create an actual instance of `Foo` inside `Bar`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case it's simple enough: since `Foo` only uses a reference to `Bar`, flipping them around will do the trick:

```
class Bar; 

class Foo{
public:
    void run(int y,Bar& bar);
};

class Bar { ... };

void Foo::run(int y, Bar& bar) {
    bar.setx(y);
}
```

You also need to move the body of `Foo::run` below, because it's actually using the `Bar` member function.

Answer (score 18):

Your problem can be reduced to this:

```
class Foo;

class Bar{
    Foo foo_; // error: incomplete type
};
```

Here you did a forward declaration for type `Foo`, i.e. a declaration without a complete definition: that's enough in C++ to declare a pointer, but not a concrete instance as you did in `Bar`.

Either give a complete definition to your class:

```
class Foo{
    // put details here
};

class Bar{
    Foo foo_; // OK
};
```

Or use (smart) pointers, e.g.:

```
class Foo;

class Bar{
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo_; // OK
};
```

Or change order declaration as pointed by [Bartek Banachewicz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44388605/6612932).